# How to convert or use Win32 libraries to another platform?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, dll, marshalling

**Description-:**

I am trying to implement Marshaling, trying to use C++ libraries in C# code in Visual Studio.

I have a C++ project that runs perfectly fine when build in Win32 solution platform, but when build in x64 solution platform throws error-:
[image]

And i have C# program that runs on x64, x86 or AnyCPU platform.

And if i try to build C++ project in Win32 platform and use the dll's created into x64,x86 or AnyCPU platform of my c# application.It shows error-:

[image]

**Requirement-:**

How can i use .dll files generated by my c++ project into my c# application.

Comment: The first error looks like mixing debug and release mode for different parts of the build. Doesn't work. The second message seems to be about 32-bit code unable to call 64-bit code (it just cannot). Check your project settings so they are consistent for all components.

Comment: @BoP I have verified its debug mode only the first error pops up when i try to change platform from Win32 to x64 and buid the solution. Is there any way to convert Win32 platform code to x64 platform code!!

Comment: Why to convert code? You were told that some of your solution or sub-projects are wrongly configured by you for x64 platform (debug/release in mix x86/x64 in mix). You post selfies about typical and clear error messages in such situation. Go and configure those correctly.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)!

Comment: your second error is due to a mix of 32 bit and 64 bit, you need to tell the c# project to use x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The first error was because of the different **Runtime Library** in
   **Project->Properties-> C/C++->Code Generation-> Runtime Library**. The issue got resolved when for all the projects there was common
   Runtime Library.
2. The second error was because of the mixing of different types of
   configuration and platform. I had my C# code in 64 bit format and
   C++ code in 32 bit, which was creating ambiguity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions here. The first is a dumb method and may not meet your needs. The second method you need to understand how to use COM components.

Solution 1: You can compile them all to win32 and you can run successfully.

Solution 2: You can write another 32bit dcom component (dll) to call your 32bit dll, set this dcom component as out of process com, and let your 64bit program call it. This method is very reliable.

Let me know if it doesn't work.